# Getting the longitude and latitude of a region from a webservice

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps, geocoding

I am building a JS application which uses google maps and needs the ability to have polygons over the states (the same shape as the state) to which colors can be applied.  Something like this:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_states4.htm

I can get something set up similar to that, but I don't have XML or data for any other regions.
What I'd really like is to be able to call a webservice with a given state, country, region, etc. and retrieve a series of lat/long coordinates laying out the given region.  I've done some initial research but haven't found anything that seems to be up to task.
Can anyone recommend a solution?

Comment: Have you tried the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/index.html)?

Comment: Yes, I use google maps to render the polygons based on the long/lat coordinates, but I'm more looking for an easy way to get those coordinates in order to render the polygons using google maps. Or do you know of a way to use the API to get coordinates of differents regions (states, countries, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a KML of all US states and capitals. You can extract the states boundaries from that file or just use the KML itself. [USA States KML](http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=usa%20states%20kml&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/us_states.kml&ei=RE--TsS4JoKfiAeu1JmBBQ&usg=AFQjCNEWXuNW1-qcDLlcVBMy2TiySDlWTQ)

Comment: Thanks. Does this mean that the kind of thing I'm looking for probably doesn't exist?  I more wanted a flexible web service where I make a call for a given country, county, state, whatever and receive a series of coordinates.

Comment: Quick search reveals some of such services are available (not sure if they cover the scope you are after) http://www.blm.gov/nils/GeoComm/home_services.html or http://www.mapquestapi.com/search/polygon-search.html or http://support.koordinates.com/entries/20182888-introduction-to-the-koordinates-api